# Oracle group by functions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following values.

```
read_count    users      manager
----------------------------------
16            Ann        Jake
12            Ann        Jake
19            Tom        Martin
```

I am trying to group the values based on the manager and take the sum of maximum read_count per user.

something like

```
select manager,sum(max(read_count)) from table group by manager
```

(I know this group by doesn't work. Just gave here for better understanding)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach.  Use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows for each user/manager combination in descending order by `read_count`.  Then, use condition sum to get only the one value per user:

```
select manager,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then read_count end) as SumMaxReadCountPerUser
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by manager, users order by read_count desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by manager;
```

You can also do this with nested `group by` statements:

```
select manager, sum(max_read_count)
from (select manager, users, max(read_count) as max_read_count
      from table t
      group by manager, users
     ) mu
group by manager;
```

I prefer the first method because it generalizes more easily, say if you want the sum of the two highest values.